# Is it possible to resize the camera preview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make the camera preview take up part of my view, rather than the entire screen. Is this even possible? Do I have to use something like the AV Foundation Framework to do this? I am new to iOS development, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use `AVFoundation` for that. In the past some people (including myself) have tried to use `UIImagePickerController` instead (by replacing its `view` property with a custom view), but it doesn't work in iOS 7 (or at least will never work as you expect). Specifying a custom preview was never a documented feature of `UIImagePickerController` to begin with, so no big surprise.

Comment: Any advice on how to get started with this? Most of the stuff I am seeing about the AVFoundation framework seems to indicate that it is intended to be used for video functionality, rather than camera.

Comment: AVFoundation is absolutely suited for taking still pictures. One thing to keep in mind is that for a camera app you need to setup your own live preview, which is technically a video feed from the camera. And then you just add a feature to take still pictures (when the user taps a button, for example). This page: http://i-software-developers.com/tag/avcapturesession-ios/ seems to have a decent explanation of how to do all that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to maintain your resultant image in same size. *Its working well for me*.

**Step 1:** First create `IBOutlet` for `UIImageview`.

**Step 2:** Add custom method into your `imagePickerController`.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        OriginalImage=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

//------Additional method placed here----
            imageview.image = image; // additional method
            [self resizeImage];
//---------
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,@selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);

    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }

}
```

Step 3: Custom method to resize images on **camera preview**

```
//---- Resize the original image ----------------------
-(void)resizeImage
{
        UIImage *resizeImage = imageview.image;

        float width = 320;
        float height = 320;

        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,320);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize,NO,0.0);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

        float widthRatio = resizeImage.size.width / width;
        float heightRatio = resizeImage.size.height / height;
        float divisor = widthRatio > heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio;

        width = resizeImage.size.width / divisor;
        height = resizeImage.size.height / divisor;

        rect.size.width  = width;
        rect.size.height = height;

        //indent in case of width or height difference
        float offset = (width - height) / 2;
        if (offset > 0) {
            rect.origin.y = offset;
        }
        else {
            rect.origin.x = -offset;
        }

        [resizeImage drawInRect: rect];

        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    imageview.image = smallImage;
    imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```